# Get meta_value from GDRating

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to get meta value from GD Rating table for each post ID with following sql:

```
$querystr = "SELECT meta_value FROM $wpdb->gdrts_itemmeta WHERE meta_key LIKE 'stars-rating_rating'";
$ratings = $wpdb->get_results($querystr);
foreach ($ratings as $rating)
{
    $rating->meta_value;
}
$ratingku = get_post_meta($post->ID, $rating, true);
```

But it failed. It return a word: "ARRAY".

How to get meta_value from another table (created by a plugin) for each post by using SQL or Query?

Comment: Is this the correct code? Because in the for loop you haven't assigned the `$rating->meta_value` to a variable.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. or maybe my code is wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: You are using the `$rating` in the `get_post_meta` but that variable is not initialized or assigned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the rating value for the post use below query:

```
global $wpdb;

$querystr = "SELECT meta_value AS rating FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_itemmeta INNER JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_items ON ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_items.item_id = ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_itemmeta.item_id AND ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_itemmeta.meta_key = 'stars-rating_rating' AND ".$wpdb->prefix."gdrts_items.id = ".$post->ID; 

$result = $wpdb->get_row($querystr);

echo $result->rating;
```

Comment: Yes, this is work for $querystr but when I try to put inside the loop of fputcsv then it get ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE.
I use following code:
global $post;
global $wpdb;
$arr_post = get_posts($arg);

foreach ($arr_post as $post)
{
 $querystr = "..................."; 
 $result = $wpdb->get_row($querystr);
 $getrating = $result->rating;
 fputcsv($file, array(
  $getrating, 
));
} 
btw thanks anyway @Jainil

Comment: @pije76 You should use $result with the condition because for some post you might get empty result. Also, which line throws you that error?

Comment: you're right. It solved now.
Thank you so much.
Btw how to get if the entity is "comments" in gdrts_items's table?

Comment: Use comment id instead of the post id in the query.